# Can't get my method to return anything

Tags: java

So, this is a class where I store data from another class called (Name) 
the class (Name) got 3 informations. Name (String)/Number List /Adress List I used the last 2 as a List so I can allow multiple adresses/numbers

now the thing is, i can't get my getContact in this code to work, it doesn't return anything, so i thought that i messed up somewhere, checked everything and things were right, so i bypassed toString and printed an object of the type Namebook is my main method and it worked just fine.

```
public class Namebook {
   private ArrayList<Name> contact;
   private Name ctc;
   public Namebook(){
   contact = new ArrayList<Name>();
   }

   public void addContact(Name name){
        this.contact.add(name);
    }

   public String getContact(){
       return String.valueOf(this.contact);
   }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.contact);
    }
}
```

---

Class (Name)

```
public class Name {
private String name;
private List<String> number;
private List<String> Adress;

public Name(String name){
  this.name = name;

 }

 public void addNumber(List<String> num){
 this.number = num;

 }

 public void addAdress(List<String> adress){
   this.Adress = adress;

 }

 public List<String> getNumber(){
   return this.number;
 }

 public List<String> getAdress(){
    return this.Adress;
 }
 public String toString() {
    return this.name + " " + getNumber() + " " + getAdress() ;
 }


 }
```

---

Main

```
public class Main {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Name person = new Name("sacha");
   ArrayList<String> add = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
    add.add("chicago");
    num.add("13213223");
    person.addNumber(num);
    person.addAdress(add);
    //System.out.println(person);
    Namebook p1 = new Namebook();
    p1.addContact(person);
    p1.getContact();

}
```

}

Comment: you have a missing accessor for `contact = new ArrayList<Name>();`

Comment: @MikeTung That is legal code. What the purpose of `ctc`, using `String.valueOf` here, or using the concrete type for the `List` I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Show us a complete example. How are you calling this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch TIL thanks amigo

Comment: `this.contact` is the `ArrayList` not the specific name in the list. What are you trying to find with `getContact()` the list of names?

Comment: @youassassin i updated the code, i'm trying to find list of names [addreses] [numbers]

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't return anything"? Why do you think it doesn't return anything? Were you expecting Java to automatically print the return value?

Comment: If you do `System.out.println(p1.getContact());` it does print the correct value..

Comment: @Vasan i'm so dumb i totally forgot, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toString` and `getContact` methods are identical, and behave identically.

Case 1:

```
System.out.println(person);
```

This is short for

```
System.out.println(person.toString());
```

Case 2:

```
p1.getContact();
```

This is not short for anything. But notice that you do not have a `System.out.println` statement. That is what **`print`s** the output of the method. Without that, nothing is printed. To fix it

```
System.out.println(p1.getContact());
```